# Simple jQuery .hover not working

Tags: jquery, hover

The following JS doesn't seem to be working. The class specified isn't adding to the element, no matter what I do, no matter where I put the JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tuobb").hover(function(){
    $('#oinfosbb').addClass('oinfosbbho');
  }, function(){
    $('#oinfosbb').removeClass('oinfosbbho');
 });
});
```

http://twenty-two.forumactif.org/
» Bottom fixed element where it's written "En ligne ([..])"

Thanks in advance

### **EDIT**

I have added the following code in one of my templates :

```
<div id="online_bb"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.get('http://twenty-one.forumactif.com/portal',function(data){jQuery('#online_bb').html(jQuery(data).find('.onlinebb').html());});</script>
```

the 'get' doesn't *go* on the same forums but it does work (and I own both forums btw), but even if I put the Js code in any related template, it doesn't work.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the JS shown, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/LdqedL01/ Do you get any errors in your browser console? Have you double-checked the class and id spellings, etc.?

Comment: Absolutely no error, and double checked everything. :l Edited first post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly, you just didn't specify any rules for `.oinfosbbho` in your CSS.

That might be why you think this is not working.
In your console just add the rule and it should be working.

Comment: I added the following in my CSS, doesn't change anything :/ :

Comment: Weeps, sorry. The added CSS :
`.oinfosbbho {background-color: red !important}`

Answer (score 1):

Where in your page are you including that JS? If possible, please reduce the issue into its smallest state, such as:

https://jsfiddle.net/mgentw5a/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tuobb").hover(function() {
    $('#oinfosbb').addClass('oinfosbbho');
  }, function() {
    $('#oinfosbb').removeClass('oinfosbbho');
  });
});
```

In there, you can see there is nothing wrong with your JS (as long as you have the css rule applied also). In the source of your page there is some script run near to the elements in question that is doing some innerHTML replacement. Try removing that first to see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just found out the "solution".

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, how stupid of me.
The following code `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.get('http://twenty-one.forumactif.com/portal',function(data){jQuery('#online_bb').html(jQuery(data).find('.onlinebb').html());});</script>` loads everything in .onlinebb.. and the JS code wasn't inside it. That was that simple.

Feel free to downvote me, I deserve it. o/